# while executing the alien_invasion getting this error. How to get rid of this?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame
import sys


def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

while True:
    screen.fill(bg_color)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type() == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.flip()
run_game()
```

This is the error iam geeting:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 19, in 
    run_game()

File "", line 14, in run_game
    if event.type() == pygame.QUIT:

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

```
if event.type() == pygame.QUIT:
```

If i keep like this also iam getting error

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `event.type` is an integer, not a function, so try:

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```